# How to get a value from radiogroup to another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button, radio-group

I want to make a new activity, like to confirm what radio-button is checked.

- I have 2 radio-groups
- Each group has 10 radio-buttons at least
- I want to take whatever radio-button is checked value to the next activity

and for sure just one radio-button can be selected from every radio-group

Here is my xml code and I want the java code

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="391dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Where Are You" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="it" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eng" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="there" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="it" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eng" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="there" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="it" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Where Do You Want To Go" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="it" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eng" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="there" />
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="it" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eng" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="there" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have deleted some of the radio-buttons so it doesn't get long

Please note I am a beginner.

Comment: Those are two separate questions. 1 is how to get the radio index, and the other is how to pass a value from one activity to another. Google separate those two that your solution you'll find!

Comment: 10 `RadioButton`'s in a line... that's overkill. How about single choice `ListView` or `Spinner` ?

Comment: @wingman there must be 2 choices from the list so i cant use listview but i dont know about the spinner can i make 2 separate spinners in the same page

Comment: @SmiLe... You can have 2 `ListView`'s or 2 `Spinner`'s in same layout.

Answer (score 2):

First, bind the RadioGroup:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
```

Then get the position of the button that was checked:

```
int checked = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Then create the intent of your next activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,nextActivity.class);
```

Then put the information you want to pass on the intent:

```
intent.putExtra("checked",checked);
```

Then start the next activity:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

On the next activity you recover that info like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int checked = intent.getIntExtra("checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

try that;

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            enter code here
            RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            String selectedRadioValue = ((RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() )).getText().toString();
            RadioGroup rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
            String selectedRadioValue2 =((RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() )).getText().toString();




           Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
           btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                  //enter code here for your control and
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), your.class);
                       intent.putExtra("radioGroup1Selected", selectedRadioValue);
                       intent.putExtra("radioGroup2Selected", selectedRadioValue2);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
             });



   }
```

get another activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String selectedRadioValue = intent.getStringExtra("selectedRadioValue");
String selectedRadioValue2 = intent.getStringExtra("selectedRadioValue2");
```

Comment: added button OnClickListener. like this? #Smile